# C# After inheritance ugliness required to access parent

Tags: c#, inheritance

my main problem here is likely wording the issue properly, hence been unable to find a suitable answer.

Using C# I have code similar to below:

```
class SlotEngine {
    // create Slots
}

class Slot {
    public SlotEngine parent;
}

class Inventory : SlotEngine {
    public void myfunc() {}
}

class OtherClass {
    void Func() {
        Slot myslot = get a slot;
        myslot.parent.myfunc(); // ofc doesnt work
        ((Inventory)(myslot.parent)).myfunc();  // does work, but ugly
    }
}
```

Is this the preferred way to tag a child class with its parent then access that parents new class after inheritance? It is definetly ugly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Are you able to move method `myfunc` into the `SlotEngine` class? You should move it to `SlotEngine` if you want to access it without casting `parent` to the `Inventory`. But it is important to know if the method `func` logically belongs to the `SlotEngine`.

Comment: it is normal practices to cast in this case, no problem, maybe it looks ugly.

Comment: should SlotEngine be abstract and define an abstract myfunc method...that way the cast isn't required...id prefer interfacing over the circular references...but thats one way to go to eliminate the cast

Comment: Without more details it's hard to say.  It might make sense to define `myfunc` in `SlotEngine`.  Or maybe you can make `Slot` generic on the `SlotEngine` type thus allowing it to be known as `Inventory`.  But often that type of casting means there's an issue with the design and it's not a bad idea to look for a way to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, been considering them. I dont think I can make SlotEngine be abstract to change this - my OtherClass  is a Drag and Drop class and that inherits an Interface to provide an OnPointerClick() method. This has the Slot and needs to use the parent (Inventory). @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ if you want to post an actual answer I would like to aknowledge that this is not as bad of a way to code as I was worried about. Really big thanks to all though, did make me think about using abstract for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no compile-time guarantee that the slot's parent will have a `myFunc` method. The call isn't type-safe. You actually should  be checking to ensure it does, like this:

```
var inventory = mySlot.parent as Inventory;
if (inventory != null)
{
    inventory.myfunc();
}
```

But a better way would be to guarantee that the type has a `myfunc` method. For example, you could define an interface, and force all possible SlotEngines to implement it.

```
interface IFuncable
{
    void myfunc();
}

abstract class SlotEngine : IFuncable
{
    abstract public void myfunc();
```

Comment: The interface does look like the better answer but the first example fits my needs better - and looks a much tidier method than what I was using. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you following changes .

Define the myfunc as virtual in the base class. i.e on SlotEngine .
Since Inventory is derived from SlotEngine , you can override myfunc in Inventory class and thus in OtherClass  you can call myfunc without type conversion .

However myfunc of SlotEngine will be called

```
  class SlotEngine
    {
        // create Slots
        public virtual void myfunc()
        {

        }
    }

    class Slot
    {
        public SlotEngine parent;
    }

    class Inventory : SlotEngine
    {
        public override void myfunc() { }
    }

    class OtherClass
    {
        void Func()
        {
            Slot myslot = get a slot;
            myslot.parent.myfunc(); 
           // ((Inventory)(myslot.parent)).myfunc();  // does work, but ugly
        }
    }
```